# Why a double dash after file/proc name in header comments?

Tags: coding-style, tcl

I was reading about TCL's coding style - at [wiki.tcl.tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/708#pagetoc9c527191) - and I can't think of a reason for one of the recommendations.

A header comment should be in the form:

```
# tcl::HistRedo --
#
...
proc tcl::HistRedo {{event -1}} {
    ...
}
```

And it stresses

> Follow the syntax [...] exactly [namely the] double-dash after the procedure name

My question is, what is the point of that double dash? Or similarly, what would go wrong, or not as good, without them? As in:

```
# tcl::HistRedo
#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer** This is largely guesswork and I may well be shot down in flames later by someone who actually *knows*...

I suspect that the coding style on the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/708#pagetoc9c527191) is the style used in the Tcl sources, and the stressed instruction to follow the syntax exactly is addressed to people who maintain those sources.

If you failed to follow that syntax exactly, I suspect that a number of tools that I speculate have been written to do *interesting things(tm)* :-) with and to the sources wouldn't find the proc definition.

I'm pretty certain that there would be no functional effect.

Comment: It's the old style that John Ousterhout promoted back when he was at Berkeley and then Sun, and it's gradually falling by the wayside. The `--` just serves as a visually distinctive thing. I've never heard of any tool that extracted them; they predate the fad for embedding consumer-readable documentation in source files.

Comment: I used it in the few lines I wrote over the weekend, and yes, it does provide a distinct mark-up. Specially in for very short names:<br># xy --<br>looks better than<br># xy<br>I guess it pre-dates code colour coding become a de facto standard, which would explain the lesser need for it and thus the decay in use (the same would probably apply to some requirements for blank lines). Thanks, I can't "accept" a comment, so I'll accept the answer and upvote the comment.